# Need to display my data from database on next tab after ajax post

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, portlet, liferay-6

Hello I am new to AJAX and JQUERY/JQUERY(UI), I have an application that has 4 tabs (1,2,3,4).

The first tab is enabled and the last 3 tabs are disabled initially. When the user clicks on the next button in the first tab it goes to the second tab. When the user clicks the button in the second tab it should go to the third tab to review or display the details of the information collected in the database, then the user clicks on the button in the third tab it goes to tab 4.

**The problem:**

Now clicking on the button in the 2nd tab, what I do is a AJAX post that takes all the form data from tab 1 and tab 2 to a Liferay Portlet Controller class in which it collects the data and insert into a database but does not return any data from this function.

The issue is when I click on the NEXT button in the second tab it goes to third tab but only shows the table header information and not the table row data (i.e its empty). The only way it shows this data is when I physically click on refresh the page browser in which goes back to first Tab then I have to go click on tab 1 and tab 2 again to see the data in the table row which is on Tab 3 that was previously inserted into the database.

Here are my code snippets. Can someone please help in how to resolve this issue? Is this suitable way of implementing this solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {                            
                               var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 0, disabled: [1,2,3]

                                   });


                                $("#additem").click(function(e){

                                    //FAULTS
                                    var fault           = $('#dd1').val();
                                    var child           = $('#childFault').val();

                                    //var childFaultVal   = $('#childFault').val;
                                    var how             = $('#faultReason').val();
                                    var noteVal         = $('#note').val();
                                    var occurenceDate   = $('#datepicker').val();


                                    if (fault == ''){
                                       alert("Please select a Stain or Damage"); 
                                      return false;
                                    }

                                    if (child == ''){
                                        alert("Please select type of "+fault);
                                         return false;
                                    } 

                                    if (occurenceDate == ''){

                                        alert("Please select the date that the "+ fault +" occured ");
                                         return false;
                                    }
                                    if (how == ''){

                                        alert("Please select how the incident happened");
                                         return false;

                                    }

                                    $tabs.tabs('enable', 1).tabs("option", "active", 1).tabs('disable', 0); 

                                    return false;

                                  });

                                   /*   $('#btn-submit').bind('click', function(){ */
                                $('#btn-submit').click(function(){  

                                      //$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){   


                                     //$tabs.tabs('enable', 2).tabs("option", "active", 2).tabs('disable', 1);

                                    //FAULTS
                                    var fault           = $('#dd1').val();
                                    var childFaultVal   = $('#childFault').val;
                                    var how             = $('#faultReason').val();
                                    var noteVal         = $('#note').val();
                                    var occurenceDate   = $('#datepicker').val();


                                    //ITEMS
                                    var itemVal               = $('#item').val();
                                    var subitemVal            = $('#subItems').val();
                                    var materialVal           = $('#material').val();
                                    var locationVal           = $('#location').val();
                                    var materialLocVal        = $('#materialLoc').val();



                                     if (itemVal == ''){

                                      alert("Please select an Item");
                                      return false;



                                    }

                                    if (subitemVal == ''){
                                        alert("Please select the type of"+itemVal);
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    if (materialVal == ''){

                                        alert("Please select a material of the "+itemVal);
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    if (locationVal == ''){

                                        alert("Please a location on the "+itemVal);
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    if (materialLocVal == ''){

                                        alert("Please select the material location of the"+itemVal);
                                        return false;
                                    }


                                    var form_data = $("form").serialize();
                                    $.ajax({
                                      type: "POST",
                                      url: "<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(reviewClaimURL.toString())%>",
                                      cache: false,
                                      data: form_data,
                                      dataType: "text",
                                      error: function() {
                                        $('#status').text('Update failed. Try again.').slideDown('slow');
                                      },
                                      success: function(response) {

                                            $tabs.tabs('enable', 2).tabs("option", "active", 2).tabs('disable', 1); 


                                      },
                                      complete: function() {
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                          $('#status').slideUp('slow');
                                        }, 3000);
                                      }
                                    });



                                });  



                                $("#addfault").click(function(){



                                    $tabs.tabs('enable', 0).tabs("option", "active", 0).tabs('disable', 1);



                                    return false;
                               });

                                $("#confirm").click(function(){
                                    $tabs.tabs('enable', 3).tabs("option", "active", 3).tabs('disable', 1); 
                                    return false;
                               }); 



                              });
```

**HTML CODE TAB 2**

```
<div id="Atab2">
                                    <p id="status"></p>
                                    <div>

                                    <strong> <label>Please Select the Item </label></strong> <select
                                        name="item" id="item"
                                        onChange="<portlet:namespace/>poputlateItemList(this);"
                                        style="width: 200px;">

                                        <option></option>
                                        <c:if test="${itemList != null}">

                                            <c:forEach var="itm" items="${itemList}">
                                                <option value="${itm.text}">
                                                    <c:out value="${itm.text}" />
                                                </option>

                                            </c:forEach>

                                        </c:if>
                                    </select>


                                    <div id="<portlet:namespace/>materialText"></div>



                                    <div align="center">


                                        <input type="button" name="btn-submit" class="button"
                                            id="btn-submit" value="NEXT" />




                                    </div>


                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </aui:form>
```

**HTML TAB3**

```
<div id="Atab3">

                                <div id=someElement>

                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Please review the following items selected. You
                                            could add additional faults or select NEXT to complete your claim</strong>
                                    </p>

                                    <table id="

    tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Fault Selected</th>
                                                <th>Item Selected</th>
                                                <th>Incident Date</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>

                                            <c:if test="${newClaimReviewList != null}">
                                            <c:forEach var="review" items="${newClaimReviewList}"

                                                    varStatus="theCount">

                                                    <%
                                                        paragraphID = Helper.getParagraphID();
                                                    %>



                                                    <c:set var="myCount">${theCount.count + 100}</c:set>
                                                    <c:set var="myChildFault">${review.childFault}</c:set>
                                                    <c:set var="myItem">${review.item}</c:set>
                                                    <c:set var="myIncidentDate">${review.incidentDate}</c:set>
                                                    <c:set var="myId">${review.id}</c:set>
                                                    <%
                                                        String myCountVal = (String) pageContext
                                                                        .getAttribute("myCount");
                                                                String myChildFault = (String) pageContext
                                                                        .getAttribute("myChildFault");
                                                                String myItem = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("myItem");
                                                                String myIncidentDate = (String) pageContext
                                                                        .getAttribute("myIncidentDate");
                                                                String myId = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("myId");
                                                                String rowName = "my_row_" + myCountVal;
                                                    %>
                                                    <div class="aui-ctrl-holder" id=<%=paragraphID%>>

                                                        <liferay-ui:icon-menu>
                                                            <tr id=<%=rowName%>>
                                                                <td>${review.childFault}</td>
                                                                <td>${review.item}</td>
                                                                <td>${review.incidentDate}</td>
                                                                <td><liferay-ui:icon-menu>
                                                                        <%
                                                                            String taglibUrl = "javascript:"
                                                                                                    + renderResponse.getNamespace()
                                                                                                    + "removeFault('" + myCountVal + "','"
                                                                                                    + myId + "')";
                                                                        %>



                                                                        <liferay-ui:icon-delete url="<%=taglibUrl.toString()%>" />

                                                                    </liferay-ui:icon-menu></td>


                                                            </tr>
                                                        </liferay-ui:icon-menu>
                                                    </div>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <br /> <br />



                                    <div align="center">

                                        <button id="addfault">ADD FAULT/ITEM</button>
                                        <button id="confirm">NEXT</button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                                 /******************************
                            * 
                            * @param actionRequest
                            * @param actionResponse
                            ***********************************/
                           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                           @ProcessAction(name = "reviewClaim")
                           public void postData(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse){
    ActionUtil.createReviewClaimDetail(actionRequest,hows,items,claim,policyId);      
                             actionResponse.sendRedirect(viewCreateNewClaim+"?id="+policyId+"&action=review");

    }
```

Here is the code to populate the HTML table

Fault Selected
                            Item Selected
                            Incident Date
                            Action

```
                    <c:if test="${newClaimReviewList != null}">
                        <c:forEach var="review" items="${newClaimReviewList}"
                            varStatus="theCount">

                            <%
                                paragraphID = Helper.getParagraphID();
                            %>



                            <c:set var="myCount">${theCount.count + 100}</c:set>
                            <c:set var="myChildFault">${review.childFault}</c:set>
                            <c:set var="myItem">${review.item}</c:set>
                            <c:set var="myIncidentDate">${review.incidentDate}</c:set>
                            <c:set var="myId">${review.id}</c:set>
                            <%
                                String myCountVal = (String) pageContext
                                                .getAttribute("myCount");
                                        String myChildFault = (String) pageContext
                                                .getAttribute("myChildFault");
                                        String myItem = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("myItem");
                                        String myIncidentDate = (String) pageContext
                                                .getAttribute("myIncidentDate");
                                        String myId = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("myId");
                                        String rowName = "my_row_" + myCountVal;
                            %>
                            <div class="aui-ctrl-holder" id=<%=paragraphID%>>

                                <liferay-ui:icon-menu>
                                    <tr id=<%=rowName%>>
                                        <td>${review.childFault}</td>
                                        <td>${review.item}</td>
                                        <td>${review.incidentDate}</td>
                                        <td><liferay-ui:icon-menu>
                                                <%
                                                    String taglibUrl = "javascript:"
                                                                            + renderResponse.getNamespace()
                                                                            + "removeFault('" + myCountVal + "','"
                                                                            + myId + "')";
                                                %>



                                                <liferay-ui:icon-delete url="<%=taglibUrl.toString()%>" />

                                            </liferay-ui:icon-menu></td>


                                    </tr>
                                </liferay-ui:icon-menu>
                            </div>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make another ajax get request to pull the data from before enabling/displaying 3 tab or set the data in model map(on your post call) and retrieve it on 3rd tab.

Comment: Here the code I am currently using to populate the html table

Comment: Hello I made another ajax get request to pull the data but I cant alter my table because I have a CSS style for the table and delete button that deletes a record. Can you be more specific when you say make another ajax call? Should I append the data to the table?

Comment: Also, should I get the data in JSON format? When I pull the data in JSON format how am I going to include in the table data, please advise. Thanks

Comment: sorry for delayed reply, create a empty div element in jsp/html and generate table element (with class names) dynamically and append it to div element. Styles will be applied automatically if you have it included.

Comment: Sample code - `var table = new Array(); table.push("<table class='some'>"); table.push("</table>"); divelement.append(table.join(""));`

Comment: HI I am doing something different. I do make the ajax call and create a record in the DB when the ajax make a post request to my Portlet class then in the callback success i go to the next tab. All works but the only problem is I don't see records in tab3. Tab 3 returns a list of records from DAO. I have to do a refresh back tab 1. Is there a way i can do a refresh in the callback success and go tab 3. Pleae advise Thanks